# How to subscribe to a specific action in Pinia

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, store, nuxtjs3, pinia

Does anyone know if it's possible to subscribe to a specific action in Pinia?
I know there's a way to subscribe to all actions like this:

```
const subscribe = someStore.$onAction(callback, false)
```

But that means I have to compare action name to the one I want within the callback, like this:

```
websocketStore.$onAction(
  ({name}) => {
    if (name === 'specificAction') {
      console.log('do something')
    }
  }
)
```

So I wonder if there's a way to it better?
(I'm using Pinia with Nuxt3)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I would also like to know how to do it :)

Comment: No, still using the same way, not ideal but it works

Comment: You can find the doc here explaining how to do it: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html#subscribing-to-actions

Comment: @elverde Most of the question is stating that the OP knows about that, but wants to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official documentation to do it but we can create a plugin to perform same operation.

```
pinia.use(({ store }) => {
  let oldAction = store.$onAction;
  store.$onAction = function(action, cb){
      olddAction((ctx) => {
          if (ctx.name === action) cb.call(store);
      }
  }
})
```

> Not tried it because never required, you can change plugin definition according to you.

Answer (score -1):

## Subscribing to actions

It is possible to observe actions and their outcome with
`store.$onAction()`. The callback passed to it is executed before the action itself. after handling promises and allows you to execute a function after the action resolves. In a similar way, `onError` allows you to execute a function if the action throws or rejects.

```
export default {
  setup() {
    const someStore = useSomeStore()

    // this subscription will be kept even after the component is unmounted
    someStore.$onAction(callback, true)

    // ...
  },
}
```

[Pinia official documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html#subscribing-to-actions)

Comment: He specifically states that he knows about `store.$onAction`, but that it is not "clean". He wants to know if there is a way to subscribe to a _specific_ action.